# How grant access to db of google VM for external ips

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine

)
On  google VM I tried open access to  db for external ip the following way

GRANT ALL ON octopus.* TO 'username'@'some_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Also I changed mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf next parameter - "bind-address".
But it doesn't work.
Maybe there is restrictions from google.
Could you suggest prompt please.
Thank you)

Comment: exactly what isn't working? you get access denied? or connection timed-out/refused?

Comment: Do you have a firewall rule in your GCE firewall to allow traffic to the IP and port? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#addingafirewall

Comment: When I try to connect to db from my local db to mysql on server, server returns next:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip' (110)

Comment: On which port your MySQL is listening? check it using this command: netstat -ln | grep mysql. The 2003 error indicates a firewall issue

Comment: using socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: @user5848681 Did you try to connect without the mysqld.sock?